# Object of nested objects to array of objects with the original key added as a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

How do I do this in Javascript please?

An object of nested objects transformed into

an array of objects with the original key now inside the object as a value.

```
let original = {
  "1": {lastSeen: 1, level: 1},
  "2": {lastSeen: 2, level: 2},
  "3": {lastSeen: 3, level: 3},
  "4": {lastSeen: 4, level: 4},
}

new = [
  {id: "1", lastSeen: 1, level:1},
  {id: "2", lastSeen: 2, level:2},
  {id: "3", lastSeen: 3, level:3},
  {id: "4", lastSeen: 4, level:4},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
let result = [];

for (let key in original) {
    result.push({ id: key, ...original[key] })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` the entries of the object and create an object with an additional `id` key

```js
const original = {
  "1": {lastSeen: 1, level: 1},
  "2": {lastSeen: 2, level: 2},
  "3": {lastSeen: 3, level: 3},
  "4": {lastSeen: 4, level: 4},
}

const output = Object.entries(original).map(([id, v]) => ({ id, ...v }))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, probably the cleanest, but went over my head. The V part.